# What nations are represented by the flags in the background in the episode Rapture?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, object-identification

In the season 5 episode "Rapture", during the ceremony scene, in the background we can see a number of colourful flags.

[image: two characters standing in front of various flags with most of the Federation flag visible]

One is quite clearly the flag of the Federation...

[image: characters in front of the other flags to be identified]

But there are at least two others that I can't quite identify. To my recollection, I don't believe I've ever seen these in any other episode. Given the nature of the episode, and that scene, it is reasonable to assume these are related to Bajor in some fashion, but I wonder if there is anything in the series that can corroborate that claim.

Is anyone aware of any information on these flags from any canon sources? (Note: I wouldn't mind anything non-canon either, if it is a reasonable statement).

**Update**

As pointed out by Richard in the comments, the author of [this website](http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/fic%5Etrk1.html#bajor) seems to have created very accurate looking representations of the flags in the background:

[image: fan website rendering of yellow and black and green, red, and blue striped flags]

---

[image: fan rendering of flag with green field and dark green corner with orange sunburst]

The website itself offers only speculation. Given what I have seen so far, it appears more likely these flags were only used in this one episode, and never seen again. Regardless, if I am wrong and there is additional information out there I have not seen yet, by all means let me know here.

Comment: For the record, it's not the flag of Bajor. When the federation recaptures DS9 in season 6, we see them unfurl the flags of the Klingon empire, the federation, and Bajor in the beginning of episode 6x07 "You Are Cordially Invited". There's an image here: http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/40275813/#/60275812
 It still could be the flag of the vedek assembly or something else of course.

Comment: @Bachrach44 I actually have one of those, but I'm not sure what that link has to do with this question. :p Did you mean to show me [this one](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/File:Promenade_Bajoran_flag.svg)? Either way, yeah you're right, its definitely not the actual Bajoran-nation flag. I agree, its possible the Vedek Assembly could be represented by one of these.

Comment: @Bachrach44  Additionally, there is an intriguing non-canon novella called [Horn and Ivory](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Horn_and_Ivory) which describes the various nations of Bajor, and their unification under one banner. Despite its non-canon origin, privately I sell it to myself that the colourful flag represents these ancient nations, though I can't say whether the writers or art directors had anything similar to that in mind when they came up with those flags

Comment: I apparently can't do cut and paste today :-). This is the link i meant to include: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-y6diAlkh15Q/TimpAUiMq6I/AAAAAAAAD2I/9PJHK2dNgqY/s1600/DSN%2BFLAGS.jpg (yes, your guess was correct).

Comment: My guess (and this is purely a guess) is that it's something like that - a flag from the planet which represents something else which is relevant. For example here in the US there is a presidential seal, a congressional seal, etc. as well as flags for the Marines, Army, etc. There's no reason to think Bajor wouldn't have a similar system.

Comment: Could it be tribal flags? Does Bahri have tribal states that all unite behind a federal Bajoran government and theocracy (under the helpful support of the Federation)?

Comment: @PaulRichter: they got [districts and provinces](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajor#Political_structure) innit, some of them might have flags.